# Nancy.Authentication.Token - Token expires at strange intervals?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, nancy

I have a strange issue (or just need to understand it better ;-)) with Nancy.Authentication.Token.

My current app requires that the token stays valid for 30 days. I have this in my bootstrapper:

```
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
        container.Register<ITokenizer>(new Tokenizer(cfg => cfg.KeyExpiration(() => TimeSpan.FromDays(60)).TokenExpiration(() => TimeSpan.FromDays(30))));
    }

    protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);
        TokenAuthentication.Enable(pipelines, new TokenAuthenticationConfiguration(container.Resolve<ITokenizer>()));
    }
```

However, at what seems like almost random intervals the token authentication fails and the user is required to login again and get a new token assigned. Sometimes this is after 4 days, sometimes after 10 days, but never has a token lasted the full 30 days.

Do you have any experience with this issue? I have tried a couple of different ways of configuring the ITokenizer but nothing seems to work permanently.

Answer (score 4):

This is my first post, so hopefully I'm following the rules.

I just started using NancyFx and started to implement token authentication myself. I'm reviewing the source code to learn how it works and also came across your post in my research.

From what I can tell, the default Tokenizer encrypts your user agent into the token at time of creation.  So if your user agent changes, the token will become invalid.  A compare is done of your current user agent from the Context to the token's stored user agent.

I would look into the possibility that your user agent may be changing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, how do you think this information could be part of a solution?

Comment: The solution would be to overwrite the AdditionalItems of the default Tokenizer config so it does not use the user agent. ".AdditionalItems(() => null)" This is not confirmed to work, but you're overwriting the default action that returns the user agent from the context.